# Low performance sending low latency messages between actors using Thespian

Tags: python, actor

I using Thespian to develop an application to consume low latency data via sockets. I had created initially two actors: one consumer (socket client connection) and the handler. Testing, I detected some delays between the time used to send one message in the consumer (Actor1) and when this message has arrived in the handler (Actor2).

To test that, I had used the following code.

```
from thespian.actors import ActorSystem, Actor

import time


class Actor1(Actor):
    def receiveMessage(self, handler, sender):
        # benchmark
        data = {'tic': time.perf_counter(), 'lim': 10000}
        print('Elapsed Time to process {} messages'.format(data['lim']))
        for i in range(data['lim']):
            self.send(handler, data)
        # perf
        toc = time.perf_counter() - data['tic']
        print('Actor 1: {} sec'.format(round(toc, 3)))
        # self.actorSystemShutdown()


class Actor2(Actor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.msg_count = 0

    def receiveMessage(self, data, sender):
        self.msg_count += 1
        if self.msg_count == data['lim']:
            toc = time.perf_counter() - data['tic']
            print('Actor 2: {} sec'.format(round(toc, 3)))

def main():
    asys = ActorSystem('multiprocTCPBase')
    consumer = asys.createActor(Actor1)
    handler = asys.createActor(Actor2)
    asys.tell(consumer, handler)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Results:**

```
Elapsed Time to process 10 messages
Actor 1: 0.002 sec
Actor 2: 0.008 sec

Elapsed Time to process 100 messages
Actor 1: 0.019 sec
Actor 2: 0.099 sec

Elapsed Time to process 1000 messages
Actor 1: 0.131 sec
Actor 2: 0.769 sec

Elapsed Time to process 10000 messages
Actor 1: 1.219 sec
Actor 2: 7.608 sec

Elapsed Time to process 100000 messages
Actor 1: 22.012 sec
Actor 2: 91.419 sec
```

Looking these results, There is something wrong or missing that I have in my code?, or there is another faster way to send the messages between actors? Also, there is any other benchmark that help us to analyze the performance [commented in the documentation](https://github.com/godaddy/Thespian/blob/master/doc/using.org#performance).

Answer (score 1):

You're sending the "handler" object as a message. Not sure how large an Actor object in Thespian is; an empty class in Python can range from a few hundred bytes to a kilobyte. I can imagine this ends up filling up a large amount of buffer space rather quickly. :)

Comment: in Thespian ```createActor()``` returns address of created actor, not the actor object itself.